# About Window in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, rubberduck, xaml

I just redid Rubberduck's About window in XAML:

[image: Rubberduck's About Window]

I do not like my XAML very much.  The way I place the `StackPanel` for the white pane over two rows, only to provide a margin to keep the copyright text out of it seems very hackish.  Just as bad is the way I put the `Hyperlink` elements in a textbox (they are not allowed to be placed directly in a `StackPanel` because it is not a `UIElement`), with the XAML-drawn logo (courtesy of ThunderFrame) inside.  Is there a cleaner way to do either of these?

```
<UserControl x:Class="Rubberduck.UI.About.AboutControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:about="clr-namespace:Rubberduck.UI.About"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="350" d:DesignWidth="499"
             d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance {x:Type about:AboutControlViewModel}, IsDesignTimeCreatable=False}">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <BitmapImage x:Key="DuckImage" UriSource="../../Resources/RD-AboutWindow.png" />
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid Background="#F6F6F6F6">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="180" />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition Height="55" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    Margin="10,10,0,10"
                    DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <Image Source="{StaticResource DuckImage}"
                    Margin="0,0,0,5"
                    Width="170"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Hyperlink Name="WebpageHyperlink"
                        NavigateUri="http://rubberduckvba.com/"
                        Command="{Binding UriCommand}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=WebpageHyperlink, Path=NavigateUri}">http://rubberduckvba.com/</Hyperlink>
            </TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1"
                    Grid.Row="0"
                    Background="White"
                    Margin="10,10,10,30"
                    Grid.RowSpan="2">
            <TextBlock Margin="10"
                       Text="{Binding Version}"
                       FontWeight="Bold"
                       VerticalAlignment="Top"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                       FontSize="14" />

            <Label Content="{Resx ResxName=Rubberduck.UI.RubberduckUI, Key=AboutWindow_AttributionsLabel}"
                   FontWeight="SemiBold"
                   FontSize="12"
                   Margin="5,0,0,0" />
            <TextBlock Margin="15,0,0,10"
                       Text="{Resx ResxName=Rubberduck.UI.RubberduckUI, Key=AboutWindow_AttributionList}"
                       FontSize="10"/>

            <Label Content="{Resx ResxName=Rubberduck.UI.RubberduckUI, Key=AboutWindow_SpecialThanksLabel}"
                   FontWeight="SemiBold"
                   FontSize="12"
                   Margin="5,0,0,0" />
            <ScrollViewer Margin="15,0,10,10"
                          Height="150">
                <TextBlock Text="{Resx ResxName=Rubberduck.UI.RubberduckUI, Key=AboutWindow_SpecialThanksList}"
                           FontSize="10" />
            </ScrollViewer>
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                    Margin="10"
                    Orientation="Horizontal">
            <!-- Circle logos created with Ai->XAML Export Plug-In Version 0.2 (PC/64) -->
            <!-- By Mike Swanson (http://blog.mikeswanson.com/)           -->
            <TextBlock>
                <Hyperlink Name="GitHubUrl"
                           NavigateUri="https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck"
                           Command="{Binding UriCommand}"
                           CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=GitHubUrl, Path=NavigateUri}"
                           TextDecorations="{x:Null}">
                    <Viewbox Width="35"
                             Height="35">
                        <Canvas Width="120"
                                Height="120"
                                Background="Transparent">
                                <Path Fill="Black"
                                      Data=" M 59.996,0.000 C 26.866,0.000 0.000,26.863 0.000,60.003 C 0.000,86.510 17.190,108.999 41.035,116.934 C 44.035,117.484 45.130,115.632 45.130,114.041 C 45.130,112.617 45.078,108.844 45.049,103.837 C 28.359,107.463 24.837,95.794 24.837,95.794 C 22.109,88.862 18.175,87.017 18.175,87.017 C 12.728,83.294 18.588,83.370 18.588,83.370 C 24.609,83.794 27.778,89.553 27.778,89.553 C 33.130,98.722 41.821,96.074 45.240,94.539 C 45.785,90.661 47.335,88.017 49.049,86.517 C 35.725,85.003 21.719,79.856 21.719,56.863 C 21.719,50.313 24.057,44.957 27.895,40.763 C 27.278,39.245 25.219,33.145 28.483,24.884 C 28.483,24.884 33.521,23.271 44.982,31.035 C 49.768,29.704 54.901,29.039 60.003,29.016 C 65.099,29.039 70.232,29.704 75.025,31.035 C 86.479,23.271 91.508,24.884 91.508,24.884 C 94.781,33.145 92.722,39.245 92.105,40.763 C 95.950,44.957 98.272,50.313 98.272,56.863 C 98.272,79.913 84.244,84.985 70.877,86.471 C 73.032,88.323 74.951,91.985 74.951,97.582 C 74.951,105.603 74.877,112.074 74.877,114.041 C 74.877,115.646 75.958,117.513 79.003,116.927 C 102.824,108.977 120.000,86.503 120.000,60.003 C 120.000,26.863 93.134,0.000 59.996,0.000 Z"/>
                        </Canvas>
                    </Viewbox>
                </Hyperlink>
                <Hyperlink Name="TwitterUrl"
                           NavigateUri="http://www.twitter.com/rubberduckvba"
                           Command="{Binding UriCommand}"
                           CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=TwitterUrl, Path=NavigateUri}"
                           TextDecorations="{x:Null}">
                    <Viewbox Margin="10,0,0,0"
                             Width="35"
                             Height="35">
                        <Canvas Width="120"
                                Height="120"
                                Background="Transparent">
                                <Path Fill="Black"
                                      Data="F1 M 92.670,42.747 C 92.702,43.460 92.718,44.177 92.718,44.897 C 92.718,66.860 76.001,92.185 45.431,92.185 C 36.045,92.185 27.310,89.433 19.954,84.718 C 21.255,84.871 22.577,84.950 23.919,84.950 C 31.706,84.950 38.872,82.293 44.560,77.836 C 37.287,77.701 31.149,72.896 29.034,66.293 C 30.049,66.487 31.090,66.591 32.161,66.591 C 33.677,66.591 35.145,66.388 36.540,66.009 C 28.937,64.482 23.208,57.765 23.208,49.712 C 23.208,49.642 23.208,49.572 23.209,49.503 C 25.450,50.748 28.013,51.496 30.737,51.582 C 26.278,48.601 23.344,43.514 23.344,37.748 C 23.344,34.703 24.163,31.848 25.594,29.393 C 33.791,39.448 46.037,46.065 59.850,46.758 C 59.567,45.541 59.420,44.273 59.420,42.970 C 59.420,33.792 66.861,26.351 76.040,26.351 C 80.820,26.351 85.139,28.369 88.171,31.599 C 91.957,30.854 95.514,29.471 98.725,27.566 C 97.484,31.447 94.849,34.704 91.417,36.761 C 94.779,36.359 97.982,35.466 100.963,34.144 C 98.735,37.477 95.917,40.404 92.670,42.747 Z M 60.000,0.000 C 26.863,0.000 0.000,26.863 0.000,60.000 C 0.000,93.137 26.863,120.000 60.000,120.000 C 93.137,120.000 120.000,93.137 120.000,60.000 C 120.000,26.863 93.137,0.000 60.000,0.000 Z"/>
                        </Canvas>
                    </Viewbox>
                </Hyperlink>
            </TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1"
                       Grid.Column="1"
                       Text="{Resx ResxName=Rubberduck.UI.RubberduckUI, Key=AboutWindow_Copyright}"
                       FontSize="8"
                       VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                       Margin="10,0,0,10"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I am satisfied with my VM, but here it is for completeness.  If anything can be improved, please bring it to my attention.

```
public class AboutControlViewModel
{
    public string Version
    {
        get
        {
            var name = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName();
            return string.Format(RubberduckUI.Rubberduck_AboutBuild, name.Version, name.ProcessorArchitecture);
        }
    }

    private ICommand _uriCommand;
    public ICommand UriCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_uriCommand != null)
            {
                return _uriCommand;
            }
            return _uriCommand = new DelegateCommand(uri =>
            {
                Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(((Uri)uri).AbsoluteUri));
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> private ICommand _uriCommand;
> public ICommand UriCommand
> {
>     get
>     {
>         if (_uriCommand != null)
>         {
>             return _uriCommand;
>         }
>         return _uriCommand = new DelegateCommand(uri =>
>         {
>             Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(((Uri)uri).AbsoluteUri));
>         });
>     }
> }
> ```

There's no reason the `ICommand` can't be `readonly`. I don't like having a getter performing assignments like this. Is the cost of instantiating a `DelegateCommand` such that lazy-initializing the field is warranted? I don't think so.

This is much cleaner IMO:

```
private readonly ICommand _uriCommand;
public ICommand UriCommand { get { return _uriCommand; } }
```

And the constructor can do the assignment, like it does with every other `private readonly` field out there, ever:

```
_uriCommand = new DelegateCommand(ExecuteUriCommand);
```

This also eliminates the "return the result of an assignment expression", which I've never come across the absolute requirement to do.

And, the rest of Rubberduck commands are implemented with `ExecuteXxxxxCommand`/`CanExecuteXxxxxCommand` full-fledged methods, which makes debugging easier if needed. An inline delegate really only serves to clutter things up and make things harder to work with when problems arise.

```
private void ExecuteUriCommand(object parameter)
{
    Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(((Uri)parameter).AbsoluteUri));
}
```